Is there a way I can use location calculated distance method on present location and data retrieved from SQLite database?
I am working on MAUI to calculate distance between two locations. I have stored the first set of locations in a SQLite database. Using location calculate distance method, I got the error:

Error CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'double' to 'Microsoft.Maui.Devices.Sensors.Location'

This is the code of my program:
return await conn.Table<Person>()
    .Where(s =>
        s.location == Location.CalculateDistance(abuja, s.location < 3.0, DistanceUnits.Kilometers))
    .ToListAsync();


Why are you passing a bool as the 2nd argument?

You can check this document about the .NET MAUI local databases.

I'm assuming here that Person.Location is Xamarin.Essentials.Location.
You have 2 comparisons of a Location with a number which doesn't make sense. I'm also assuming you don't have an implicit conversion in your code to convert a location to a number too.

s.location < 3, and
s.location == Location.CalculateDistance(...)

Also, none of the overloads of Location.CalulateDistance accept a boolean value either.
Assuming abuja is another instance of Location, did you mean?
return await conn.Table<Person>()
    .Where(s =>
        Location.CalculateDistance(abuja, s.location, DistanceUnits.Kilometers) < 3.0)
    .ToListAsync();

This should filter the list of People that are less than 3km from abuja.
